# what's the meaning of ぎじゅつしゃ?

Tags: grammar

There's s hotel resident asking the receptionist that the AC doesn't work . 
so the worker told him 
"スイッチをぎじゅつしゃ押してください" 
I don't know what's the meaning of "ぎじゅつしゃ" here ?

Comment: The sentence is likely be in a instruction book for an air conditioner made in China. Making no sense to me. Could you get back to the original source?

Comment: Ah, may be not '押してください' but '呼んでください' isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

ぎじゅつしゃ is in kanji 技術者, which means 'engineers' in general.

In this case most sufficient translation would be technical service or electricians.

And the original sentence would be

> スイッチのぎじゅつしゃを呼んでください。

Call the electricians for the switch, please.

Then, the sentence makes a little sense.
Anyway get back and check with the source.